# Unable to select radio buttons via the label text in widget form

Tags: wordpress

I'm unable to select radio buttons via the label text in widget the form. The following code was recommended by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) and works fine in jsFiddle, but not in WordPress's widget form area.

```
<p>
    <input type="radio" id="channel_id" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'channel_type' ) ); ?>" value="channelid" <?php echo ($channel_type == 'channelid') ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
    <label for="channel_id">Channel ID</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="channel_name" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'channel_type' ) ); ?>" value="channel" <?php echo ($channel_type == 'channel') ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
    <label for="channel_name">Channel name</label>
</p>
```

What is happening in the Wordpress widget area to change this functionality?

Thanks.

**Edit:** This code is placed in the form method in a class extending WP_Widget. It's a modified version of the example found here https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API

**Fiddle:** Here is the output from the browser https://jsfiddle.net/n2fole00/xjo86zc7/ as you can see, it works in jsFiddle, but not from the Wordpress widget panel.

Comment: How are you running PHP inside widget form?

Comment: I should have mentioned, it's put in a function called `form` in a class that extends `WP_Widget`. Example code here https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
    <input type="radio" id="channel_id" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'channel_type' ) ); ?>" value="channelid" <?php echo ($this->get_field_name( 'channel_type' ) == 'channelid') ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
    <label for="channel_id">Channel ID</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="channel_name" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'channel_type' ) ); ?>" value="channel" <?php echo ($this->get_field_name( 'channel_type' ) == 'channel') ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
    <label for="channel_name">Channel name</label>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not what I was asking. It's not about getting the saved state of the last selection, which works fine in my code, but rather the button state is meant to change when you select the label text. The pointer is activated on-hover, but the click event does not select the connected radio button .

Comment: Then either share fiddle or the JS you are using

Comment: Updated the question with a jsFiddle example. There is no JS for this widget.